# Check if two values overlap lower and upper value

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with some logic here.

In my MySQL database I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | lower | upper
1  | 0     | 120
2  | 121   | 200
3  | 201   | 500
```

Now, my form posts two values e.g. 121 and 300.

What query can get those rows where 121 to 300 overlap the lower and upper columns?

In this example these rows are: 2 and 3

I just can't figure it out..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE lower <= 300 AND upper >= 121
```

Comment: That's not what I ment because this only covers if the posted range is BETWEEN the upper and lower values, the posted range isn't allowed to overlap the lower and upper range..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE (121 <= lower AND 300 >= lower) OR (121 <= upper AND 300 >= upper)
```

This works perfectly